# Is It necessary to write in mesh equation of Kirchoff's voltage law the voltage of current source?

Tags: current-source, mesh-analysis

I want to do mesh analysis so I wrote the mesh equations but I am not sure which is the right mesh1 or equation4 equation (these 2 equation are for mesh 1 ) ? has to write the voltage *Vx* everytime I use mesh 1 equation?

[image]

**mesh1**
$$
Vx + 5 \ast \left ( I1 - I3 \right ) + \frac{\mathrm{d} \left ( I1 - I2 \right )}{\mathrm{d} t} + 8\ast \frac{\mathrm{d}I3 }{\mathrm{d} t} = 0
$$

**equation 4**
$$
 5 \ast \left ( I1 - I3 \right ) + \frac{\mathrm{d} \left ( I1 - I2 \right )}{\mathrm{d} t} + 8\ast \frac{\mathrm{d}I2 }{\mathrm{d} t} = 0
$$

**mesh2**
$$
[16\ast \frac{\mathrm{d} \left ( I2 - I1 \right )}{\mathrm{d} t} - 8\ast\frac{\mathrm{d} I3}{\mathrm{d} t} + 60\ast I2 = 0
$$

**mesh 3**
$$
4\ast \frac{\mathrm{d} I3}{\mathrm{d} t} - 8\ast\frac{\mathrm{d} \left ( I2 - I1 \right )}{\mathrm{d} t} + 20 \ast \left ( I3 - I2 \right ) + 5\ast (I3 - I1) = 0
$$

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write a KVL equation for a loop that contains a current source, you must include the voltage across the current source. Your "equation 4" is not a correct equation to describe your circuit.

But you can't write the voltage across the current source as a function of the current through it (since it produces the same current for any voltage). So writing this equation won't help you solve the circuit.

The resolution for your simple circuit is just to remove the mesh 1 equation from your system of equations and just write

$$I_1 = I_{src},$$

where \$I_{src}\$ is the known value of the source.

Comment: I agree but if I  don't know the value of I1 how can I solve it?

Comment: @vg97, if you don't know \$I_1\$ you can't solve this circuit. You could find all the other voltages and currents as a function of \$I_1\$, though.

Comment: if I want only write mesh equation I will write 'I1 = Isrc' and this will be the mesh 1 equation?

Comment: @vg97, if you only want to write the mesh equations then your "mesh 1" equation is correct (except the last term should involve \$I_3\$, not \$I_2\$). But it won't help you to solve the circuit.

Comment: ok thanks for your help I changed it